# Deregister scripts from plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I have an own class that deregisters all scripts and styles and creates 2 cached files one for scripts and one for styles that is registered in the end. This runs inside theme, my problem is that I cant move it into plugin, as soon as i move it into plugin it wont work.

currently this code works inside theme

```
add_filter('wp_print_styles', array($this, 'optimize_styles'), 1);
add_filter('wp_print_scripts', array($this, 'optimize_scripts'), 1);
```

i have tried add action add filter, change priorities.... also i want some way to make my plugin load as last to ensure all plugin styles and scripts will be "compiled" into one.

Thankyou

Comment: Without seeing your code I am not sure how to address your problem.

Comment: To load your custom plugin last, remember that plugins do load by alphabetical order of plugin's folder name (not by plugin's name). So name it ZZ... :)

Comment: @ErikKubica There's a much better/"correct" way to do this - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much better and more reliable way than naming your plugin "ZZ" - use a delayed hook on `plugins_loaded`, which fires after all plugins are loaded:

```
function wpse_191178_plugins_loaded() {
    // Do your stuff
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_191178_plugins_loaded', 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since plugins are loaded by the alphabetical order of plugin's folder name (not by plugin's name), name your plugin folder ZZ.. and it should load last :-)